# Keeping informed the data source of table view in view controller class from a singleton class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, singleton, tcpclient

i have stumbled upon with the problem that i must update my data source in view controller class from singleton `TCPConnection` class. I have the callback function of server in singleton `TCPConnection` class but when i receive data i must update the data source of table view in view controller class. Can you offer a solution for this scenario, thanks in advance.

Comment: Use Delegation, NotificationCenter or KVO. I prefer delegation.https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegation is your friend. You will want to declare a delegate protocol (you can do this in your TCPConnection.h), and add a delegate property to your TCPConnection class of type `id<TCPConnectionDelegate>` (`@property (nonatomic, weak) id<TCPConnectionDelegate> delegate;`).

You can then set your viewController as the delegate for your TCPConnection instance.

Then, in your TCPConnection implementation, you will need to send a message to your delegate when new data is received (passing that data along with the message).

Answer (score 2):

I'll use `NSNotificationCenter`:
Subscribe to the service (the subscriber):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:<your_controller>
                                         selector:@selector(method)
                                             name:@"name_of_notification"
                                           object:<any_linear_object_u_want>];
```

Now the sender will post the `NSNotificationCenter`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"name_of_notification" object:<any_linear_object_u_want>];
```

At the receiver selector u can invoke

```
[self.your_table reloadData];
```

The `reloadData` operation can be heavy, if u've got any performance issues, try some other reload instead.

Good Luck